# Vertx, event bus with blocking reply

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I have two Verticles,
 one to send some data to event bus and one to receive data from event bus then reply after some sleep

My code is:

Sender:

```
public class Sender extends AbstractVerticle{

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        final EventBus eventBus = this.vertx.eventBus();
        this.vertx.setPeriodic(1000, handler->{
            eventBus.<JsonObject>send("test", new JsonObject().put("d", "d"),this::handle);
        });
    }
    private  void handle(AsyncResult<Message<JsonObject>> result) {
        if(result.succeeded()){
            System.out.println("Answer: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(result.result().body());
        } else{
            result.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        final EventBus eventBus = this.vertx.eventBus();
        eventBus.<JsonObject>consumer("test",this::handle);
    }

    private void handle(final Message<JsonObject> event) {
        System.out.println("Get: "+event.body());
        sleep();
        System.out.println("Response: ");
        event.reply("Hello");
    }


    private void sleep(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Receiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I run both verticles separately using cluster mode

This is the output from receiver verticle:

```
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
Response:
Get: {"d":"d"}
```

But output from sender verticle is empty then it show me errors

```
 Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address: 26d073b1-e97a-4d9b-88b7-0b9fbe61cb25, repliedAddress: test
```

I know that it happen when there is no result during 30 s but why it's happen when my sleep is only 2 sec.

And second question , maybe i miss something fron official docs but how Vertx can be asynchronius when all callback's code use event loop thread and to avoid this behavior we should to create worker thread for each long task?

Thank in advance

Comment: Regarding second question - please ask it as a separate post with appropriate title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code example you provided work ok on my PC (java 9 + vertx 3.5.1).
But, there's an issue with it - in the `Sender` verticle handler method has the following signature - `handle(AsyncResult<Message<JsonObject>> result)`. It means that it was for a reply instance of JsonObject, but in `Receiver` verticle you reply with `event.reply("Hello")` which is a simple sting. So you update your handler in `Sender` verticle to:

```
JsonObject body = result.result().body();
System.out.println(body);
```

There will be an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject
```

So if you reply with `JsonObject` from `Receiver` verticle, or change reply handler in `Sender` to consume `String` - it will work okay.